# Convergence of functions with different domains

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $C([0,T],\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a set of all continuous functions from $[0,T]$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a norm $\|f(\,)\| = \max\{\|f(t)\|\mid t\in[0,T]\}$. For all $T>0$, let $C_T \subset C([0,T],\mathbb{R}^n)$ be a nonempty compact subset such that if $T_1 < T_2$, then $C_{T_2\mid T_1} \subset C_{T_1}$ where
\begin{equation}
C_{T_2\mid T_1} = \{f(\,)\in C([0,T_1],\mathbb{R}^n)\mid \exists g(\,)\in C_{T_2},\, f(t) = g(t),\, t \in [0,T_1]\}.
\end{equation}
Can we say that there exists a nonempty compact subset $C_\infty \subset C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $C_{\infty\mid T} \subset C_T$ for all $T>0$?

Comment: One could use Zorn's lemma to show that there is always a non-empty subset $C_\infty$ with the claimed properties. Perhaps there is an easier way.

Comment: @daw - Can you please explain how Zorn's lemma guarantees a compact subset $C_{\infty}$ with the desired property?

Comment: It would be a proof similar to Hahn-Banach extension theorem, to guarantee the existence of a continuous function $f$, such that the restriction of $f$ to $[0,T]$ is in $C_T$ for all $T>0$.

Comment: Yes, but how will you guarantee that $C_{\infty}$ is a compact set?

Answer (score 0):

Let $0<T_1<T_2<\cdots$ and $T_i \to \infty$ as $i\to\infty$. Since $C_{T_j}$ is compact in $C([0,T_j],\mathbb{R}^n)$, $C_{T_j\mid T_i}$ is compact in $C([0,T_i],\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $i < j$. Since $C_{T_{j+1}\mid T_j} \subset C_{T_j}$, $C_{T_{j+1}\mid T_i} \subset C_{T_j\mid T_i}$ for all $i < j$, so $C_{T_i} \supset C_{T_{i+1}\mid T_i} \supset C_{T_{i+2}\mid T_i} \supset \cdots$. Therefore, $D_{\infty\mid T_i} := \bigcap_{k=i}^\infty C_{T_k\mid T_i} \neq \emptyset$ where $C_{T_i\mid T_i} = C_{T_i}$. Note that if $k > 1$, then $\forall f(\,) \in C_{T_k\mid T_1}$, $\exists g(\,) \in C_{T_k\mid T_2}$ such that $f(t) = g(t)$ if $t\in[0,T_1]$. Since $D_{\infty\mid T_1} = \bigcap_{k=2}^\infty C_{T_k\mid T_1}$ and $D_{\infty\mid T_2} = \bigcap_{k=2}^\infty C_{T_k\mid T_2}$, $\forall f(\,)\in D_{\infty\mid T_1}$, $\exists g(\,)\in D_{\infty\mid T_2}$ such that $f(t) = g(t)$ if $t \in [0,T_1]$. In other words, for all $f(\,) \in D_{\infty\mid T_1}$ there exists an extension of $f(\,)$ to $[0,T_2]$. By repeatedly applying the same procedure, $f(\,)$ can be extended to $[0,\infty)$. Let $f(\,) \in D_{\infty\mid T_1}$ and $f_\infty(\,) \in C([0,\infty),\mathbb{R}^n)$ be the extension of $f(\,)$. Then, $C_{\infty} = \{f_\infty(\,)\}$ is a compact subset such that $C_{\infty\mid T} \subset C_T$ for all $T>0$.